# Ubuntu 16.04 install on Acer Aspire 5560-7402 Operating System not found

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, uefi, acer

tl;dr: installed 12.04 and it works. installed 16.04 and it does not work. Seems to be UEFI related.

Had Ubu 12.04 running on the Acer Aspire just fine.
Did an apt-get dist-upgrade to get the latest kernel. It failed because the /boot partition was full. Fixed that by deleting old linux-images and reinstalled latest linux-image to make sure it was ok. Failed to reboot. I believe it said it could not find a bootable device. The Acer has an SSD and a DVD drive.

Searched the web. Said boot to livecd and run some commands.
Lost my copy of 12.04 livecd so I created a 16.04 version. The Acer wouldn't boot from the 16.04 LiveCD - the DVD spins, lots of whirring and stuff and then ... dead silence. Left it for 10 - 15 minutes (perhaps it's really really slow?) and nothing, just hangs with a black screen.

No problem. I'll just wipe the drive and upgrade to 16.04. The ubuntu installation starts up fine. Note there was that pesky dialog box that says UEFI installation detected, do you want to continue? I said yes.

Installs with no problem. Gets all the way to the end, ejects the DVD and everything. Looks good.

On the reboot there is a message "Operating System not found".

Searched the web. There are sites out there about "no bootable device". Not really my exact problem anymore.

Searched the web. There are solutions for "OS not found" but in a dual boot environment. Not exactly my scenario, but what the heck, I'll try that. It said boot to livecd. Nope, no go on that front. Same deal, black screen, no explanation of what's going on.

Searched the web. Said enable/disable UEFI in the BIOS. Reboot, hit F2. There is no option to enable or disable UEFI.

Searched the web. Tried to find out if this Aspire is UEFI, could not find an answer. I think it is, because I (vaguely) remember it had some version of windows on it when I bought it.

Searched the web. Said try entering a security password. I did, reboot, but still "OS not found".

I've run out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you boot to upgrade? You say the DVD would not boot. Or can you boot the installer but not the live session?

Comment: Yes I booted to the DVD to install. So that worked.

But the boot to the DVD to run Ubuntu from the DVD (i.e. LiveCD) did not work. It just hung.

> Or can you boot the installer but not the live session?
Exactly.